# Call to a member function query() on null - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here is code:

```
$connect = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if($connect->connect_errno) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $connect->connect_error);
   exit();
}

function send($username="", $password="") {
    $connect->query("INSERT INTO table1 (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
 }
$connect->close();
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: connect in C:\xampp\htdocs\playground01\build\components\includes\root.php on line 44
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\playground01\build\components\includes\root.php on line 44

Where is a problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in PHP. `$connect` is defined outside `send` so it is inaccessible. Either pass it as a parameter, define it in the function, or use `global`.

a)

```
function send($username="", $password="", $connect) {
    $connect->query("INSERT INTO table1 (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
 }
$connect->close();
```

Then in the `send` call pass the `$connect`.

b)

```
function send($username="", $password="", $connect) {
    $connect = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
if($connect->connect_errno) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $connect->connect_error);
   exit();
}
    $connect->query("INSERT INTO table1 (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
 }
$connect->close();
```

c)

```
function send($username="", $password="") {
    global $connect;
    $connect->query("INSERT INTO table1 (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
 }
$connect->close();
```

Additional you should be using [parameterized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Query_Parameterization_Cheat_Sheet#Parameterized_Query_Examples) with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

A third note, passwords should not be stored in plaintext, http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **declare which global variables you are going to use** in the function if you want to do so:

```
function send($username="", $password="") {
    global $connect;
    $connect->query("INSERT INTO table1 (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
}
```

Or even better, **make the connection a function parameter**:

```
function send($connect, $username="", $password="") {
    $connect->query("INSERT INTO table1 (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
}
```

Comment: Good lord it is bad to do that

Comment: @Jonathan No doubt about that, but that was not the question here.

Comment: you should explain why use of globals is nasty in this answer as well